# FreeIPA: unable to run ipa commands

Tags: redhat, kerberos, openldap, mit-kerberos, freeipa

I have installed FreeIPA server and created one user.After some time user account got locked so I tried to unlock it using `ipa user-unlock` but I am faicng issue while Performing ipa commands .Following is the issue that I am facing:

```
ipa: ERROR: cannot connect to u'https://fqdn/ipa/xml': Authorization Required
```

Following are the logs of httpd:
*

> gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code
>   may provide more information (, Wrong principal in request), referer:
>   https://fqdn/ipa/xml

*

If i try to get ticket for that user I am getting the following error:

```
kinit: Clients credentials have been revoked while getting initial credentials
```

Answer (score 1):

Authenticate (`kinit`) as `admin` or some other user with the *System: Unlock User* permission, then run `ipa user-unlock` as that user.